# Code design question: Is using [self view]; or [self window]; a bad practice?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

It has come to my attention that if one calls [self view]; or [self window]; within, respectively, an init method of NSViewController or NSWindowController, then all the IBOutlets become available right there in the init method.

Would you regard it a bad programming practice to do so?

For NSWindowController, I suppose it's better to use the "windowDidLoad" method to guarantee the outlets are connected. But what about NSViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; don't cause the nib to be loaded unless and until you absolutely need to access any of the objects in the nib. Let the controller be lazy, as it is designed to be.

> For NSWindowController, I suppose it's better to [do my set-up in] the "windowDidLoad" method to guarantee the outlets are connected [by then]. But what about NSViewController?

Override `loadView`. Send `[super loadView]`, then do whatever you need to do that requires the view to have been loaded.

Edit: As ughoavgfhw notes, `awakeFromNib` is also a good choice, possibly even a better one.

Answer (score 2):

An IBOutlet will never be connected in the initializer method. If you want to do something with objects in nibs, you need to use `awakeFromNib`, or, in the specific case of NSWindowController, `windowDidLoad`.

Comment: As he said in the question, a VC or WC that sends itself `view` or `window` will cause the nib to be loaded. By the time that message returns the view or window, the nib has been completely loaded, so all the outlets will have been connected as a side effect.